# outsource jQuery mobile content

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an **JQuery Mobile PhoneGap** App for Android at the moment (multipage template, only one html page).

Make it sense, to outsource extensive content like an imprint? So that the index.html is smaller.

---

If it make sense, what is the best way to do that? 
I would like to outsource some text with html tags like:

```
<p><b>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie.<br />

Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica,<br />
li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. <br />

213214532532432143434<br />
676435432543543<br />

refusa: <a href="mailto:quande@quande.com">desirabilite de un nov </a><br />
pronunciation: <a href="http://www.quande.com" target="_blank">quande</a> <br /></p>
```

I tried that,

```
jQuery.get('test.txt', function(data) {
    $('#imprint_content').html(data.replace('\n','<br>'));
});
```

But I get this error:

> OPTIONS file:///D:/xxx/assets/www/test.txt No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>   jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/xxx/assets/www/test.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1

---

Edit: If I upload test.txt on a server. I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.abc.com/test.txt. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Downvote without a comment, why?

Comment: about the access origin error with a remote server, configure access origin in your config.xml for files in the app is shouldn't be needed (unless you haven't at least 127.0.0.1*)

Comment: previous comment was about running in a phonegap app. watching the log  file:///D:/xxx/assets/www/test.txt, it seems you are opening your page from your computer browser. Is that what you're doing?